# Delete and add nodes with click on a node in d3.js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

How to add or remove nodes and links with `onclick` event in my code?

Here is my ([d3js](http://d3js.org/)) [code fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AbwQ/1/).

**How to use:** Right click on any node and click on delete it remove all nodes but no link.
But I want to remove only one node and it's links that is click for delete.

```
//right click menu items
$('g.node').contextMenu('cntxtMenu',
{
    itemStyle:
    {
        fontFamily : 'Arial',
        fontSize: '13px'
    },
    bindings:
    {
        'open': function(t) {
            alert(t.__data__.name);
        },
        'email': function(t) {
            alert('Trigger was '+t.__data__.name+'\nAction was Email');
        },
        'save': function(t) {
            alert('Trigger was '+t.__data__.name+'\nAction was Save');
        },
        'delete': function(t) {
            $('g.node').remove();
            //alert('Trigger was '+t.__data__.name+'\nAction was Delete');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: First you need to replace `$('g.node').remove();` with `$(t).remove();`

Comment: @ArunPJohny ok good now how to remove it's links

Comment: Here is working example see on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AbwQ/3/)

Comment: Could you please post an answer to your question and accept it?

Comment: Here is working example see on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5AbwQ/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use $(t) instead of $('g.node')

```
   'delete': function(t) {
        $(t).remove();

    }
```

[See Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/5AbwQ/51/)